# Postgresql restore Error at or near "`"

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have 800mb backup postgresql db, i even had hardtime to open the file because not enough memory.

I tried to restore the file, but i receive this error while restoring, does any one know how to fix

I run this command:
psql -U root -d mydatabase -f dbfile.sql

i receive message:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO`cv_balance` VALUES (4279704,3431,'2008-08-10 2...

please help

Comment: I just had a similar but not equal problem: loading a dump always gave syntax error on line 1, even if line 1 looked correct (and even if line 1 was just a comment). It turned out the sql file had Windows-style CRLF line breaks. I converted to Unix-style, problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like for some reason, a ` mark got either added after cv_balance or removed before cv_balance - look on the first line of your SQL file, it currently probably reads something like this:

```
INSERT INTO cv_balance` VALUES    ...(continued)...
```

modify it to read like this:

```
INSERT INTO cv_balance VALUES     ...(continued)...
```

(i.e. remove the errant backquote)

If you need an editor that can handle large files, try something like vim.